# Suspicious email: we are conducting research on the evolution of Stack Overflow

Tags: support, phishing

Just received this and won't be doing anything with it, but thought it should be flagged to SO somehow:

> From: Manik Hossain md_ai@encs.concordia.ca via mailchimpapp.net
>
> Hello Software Engineer,
>
> We hope this email finds you well.
>
> We are a group of researchers from Concordia University and Queen's
>   University in Canda and recently, we are conducting research on the
>   evolution of Stack Overflow. We are hoping that you could help us by
>   filling out a short survey about your experience of using Stack
>   Overflow.
>
> The survey contains 24 questions and should only take 5 to 10 minutes
>   to complete. We really appreciate your participation. Your input will 
>   help our research towards understanding and improving the Stack Overflow community.
>
> The link to our survey:
>   https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSccDMVUgnMM7RPvcwUKyAStM9GSFF3fFt4XkxbTgfGHqssbgA/viewform
>
> Yours sincerely,
>
> Manik, Concordia University (Canada)